# WinForms control alignment and size issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inheritance, alignment

My form hosts a `TabControl` control with multiple tabs. Of those, two tabs (correlated) need to display the same data, for which, I am using one `DataGridView` (DGV) control. The DGV control is added to the first tab in design mode and at runtime I move the DGV control to the next tab when clicked (using code in the `...Tab_Enter` event handler), and vice-versa.

The above setup works just fine when the form is not maximized. But when I maximize the window and switch between the two tabs, the DGV control gets enlarged and misaligned (see attached screenshots). Below is structure of my form.

```
Form > InputForm > ProductInputForm > HeaderPanel > TabControl > DataGridView
```

`InputForm` is a custom base form. `HeaderPanel` is a custom user control. Both `HeaderPanel` and `TabControl` have `Anchor` property set to `Top|Bottom|Left|Right`, and DGV is set to `Bottom|Left|Right` respectively.

I have tried setting the `Form.AutoScaleMode` to `None` but with no luck. Also tried to play around with the `Anchor` property but did not help as well. Please help resolve this issue.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: So the problem is it grows with the form if I understand correctly? Does giving it a fixed size help? And wouldnt those 3 anchor points cause it to grow? If you have 1 anchor for horizontal (so left/right) and 1 for vertical (top/bottom) it shouldnt grow.

Comment: I don't see a problem simply using two grids for the same data. It doesn't add complexity. But reparenting controls at runtime adds complexity you shouldn't do if not really needed. So why do it in the first place?

Comment: @EpicKip - The DGV does grow properly with the anchor points but not when the Form is maximized.

Comment: @Ralf - I agree. I thought it was redundant. Buy why is this an issue only when the Form is maximized?

Comment: @SanthoshShanmugam Ah so it should actually grow? Its not fully clear to me what it is you want

Comment: FYI - I've had issues with controls getting enlarged, misaligned in design mode as well (in other scenarios)

Comment: @EpicKip - I want the DGV to stay as it is in screenshot 1 when the window is maximized. Instead it gets misaligned as seen in screenshot 2.

Comment: You'll probably have to override `OnLayout` and layout the controls yourself.

Comment: Host the two grids in a two rows [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). Set a fixed row height for the second row. The first row height is auto.

Comment: I think EpicKip has it right, and the simplest. If you don't want the DGV to resize, set the anchors.

Comment: @dr.null's idea seems to be a viable workaround for my scenario. I got it working with a `Panel` control. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for asking. However, you've solved the problem on your own using a `Panel` rather than what I've suggested. So, the answer is yours. Good luck.